# Can't submit a Review into a Place - Rails Directory Website app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model-view-controller, partials

I am following a Rails tutorial where I have to create a directory website of places in which an user can submit a review.

Right now, here's the thing:

I can register an user and I am able to login. Once I am logged in, I also can create a new place into the database. I also can access the webpage of each place I have created.

I have a problem though. On each place page, I can't submit the review of the place.

All places have an address, a phone number, a website, a description and a map with the location of that place. On that same page I have a form to submit a review, however, once I click on the create review button nothing happens. I can't see the review on the page and when I go to the rails console I can definitely see that there's not a single review created.

Inside my app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb I have this code:

```
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :content, required: true %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :place_id, required: true, value: @place_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Inside my app/views/reviews/_review.html.erb I have this code:

```
<p>
    <%= gravatar_tag review.user.email, size: 20 %><%= review.content %> by <%= review.user.name %>
</p>
```

Inside my app/views/places/show.html.erb I have this code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h3><%= @place.name %></h3>
    <p><strong>Adress</strong><%= @place.address %></p>
    <p><strong>Phone</strong><%= @place.phone %></p>
    <p><strong>Website</strong><%= @place.website %></p>
    <p><strong>Description</strong><%= @place.description %></p>
    <div id="map-canvas" style = "width:230px; height:230px"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
    <h3>Reviews by People</h3>
    <% if current_user %>
    <h5>New Review</h5>
    <%= render 'reviews/form' %>
    <h5>All Reviews</h5>
    <%= render @reviews %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

On my places_controller.rb I have:

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /places
  # GET /places.json
  def index
    @places = Place.all
  end

  # GET /places/1
  # GET /places/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = @place.reviews
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /places/new
  def new
    @place = Place.new
  end

  # GET /places/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /places
  # POST /places.json
  def create
    @place = current_user.places.new(place_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.save
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /places/1
  # PATCH/PUT /places/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.update(place_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /places/1
  # DELETE /places/1.json
  def destroy
    @place.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to places_url, notice: 'Place was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_place
      @place = Place.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def place_params
      params.require(:place).permit(:name, :address, :description, :phone, :website)
    end
end
```

Also, so far... here is my reviews.controller.rb code:

```
class ReviewsController <ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        format.html { redirect_to place_path(@review.place) , notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to place_path(@review.place), notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to place_path(@review.place), notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])  
  end

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:content, :place_id)
  end


end
```

Any insight of why I can't save reviews of a place?

Comment: Where's `@place_id` defined?

Comment: Humm, though call as I'm not sure. What would be useful for me to update the question? Places controller? Places view?

Comment: I mean, if `_form.html.erb` is rendered within the `places#show`, but your show method has just `@reviews` and `@review`.

Comment: As far as I could follow what I have done before, it was never needed to put something else on the show method. I will update the question with the full places_controller file, just in case.

Comment: It is in before_action set_place

Comment: @rohan your answer worked but I am afraid I did not understood what have I done. I mean, I am now confused with what it means place_id and place.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should your form be like this:-

```
<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :content, required: true %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :place_id, required: true, value: @place.id %>
</div>
```

You are setting instance variable @place in controller. So you need to use @place.id in your rendered views. You have not set @place_id anywhere